# Decimal column in R taken as a string not a decimal

Tags: r, csv

This is my CSV file:

```
"Product","Total","Destrio","TotDestrio","Percent"
ANGELLE DIRECT,60904,0,60904,0
CHERRY AMARILLO,60538,9071,69609,13.0313608872
CHERRY AMARILLO PER,20486,5042,25528,19.7508617988
CHERRY EN RAMA,186055,31826,217881,14.6070561453
```

So I use this:

```
prod <- read.csv("file.csv",header=T)
prod$Percent <- as.numeric(prod$Percent)
prod$Percent <- factor(prod$Percent, levels =
                         unique(prod[order(prod$Percent),"Percent"]))
```

But `prod$Percent <- as.numeric(prod$Percent)` doesn't convert to number and `prod$Percent <- factor(prod$Percent, levels =unique(prod[order(prod$Percent),"Percent"]))` doesn't order by this field `Percent`

I need `Percent` to be a decimal, not a string and order by this field in descending order.

Comment: (-1, sorry) Your CSV file provides 4 column headers but 5 value columns

Comment: Im sorry I forgot it!

Comment: Ok, Raffael. But do you know how do it?

Comment: now I have to give you +2 ... ;)

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. For starters, the data you show reads in just fine for me. When you say "doesn't convert to Number" you need to explain what that means. Warnings? Error messages?

Comment: "doesn't convert to Number" means: do not take the percent as a Decimal or number. Percent is taken as a String, and represented in ggplot2 as a category (non continous)

Comment: Ok, I think we're having difficulty communicating because of some language issues. Your previous comment is ambiguous about whether you are describing _what you want to happen_ or _what actually does happen_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the CSV and everything is fine. The "Percent" column IS numeric. Then you order by it. Actually that's all.

```
> prod <- read.csv("f:\\temp\\test.csv",header=T)

> str(prod)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Product   : chr  "ANGELLE DIRECT" "CHERRY AMARILLO" "CHERRY AMARILLO PER" "CHERRY EN RAMA"
 $ Total     : int  60904 60538 20486 186055
 $ Destrio   : int  0 9071 5042 31826
 $ TotDestrio: int  60904 69609 25528 217881
 $ Percent   : num  0 13 19.8 14.6

> sum(prod$Percent)
 [1] 47.38928

> prod[order(prod$Percent),]
              Product  Total Destrio TotDestrio  Percent
1      ANGELLE DIRECT  60904       0      60904  0.00000
2     CHERRY AMARILLO  60538    9071      69609 13.03136
4      CHERRY EN RAMA 186055   31826     217881 14.60706
3 CHERRY AMARILLO PER  20486    5042      25528 19.75086
```

Comment: It reads in fine with `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` for me, so that probably isn't the issue.

Comment: ...if `Percent` isn't numeric, it's (probably) because there is something further down in the full csv (that they haven't shown) that is actually not numeric.

Comment: it is the issue. he confuses the purpose of factors as I understand. now it is numeric and ordered by $Percent.

Comment: Percent is XX.XXX, so is numeric or decimal.

Comment: `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` doesn't convert strings to numeric.

Comment: @Henrik: nobody says that

Comment: Works and now take Percent as a number, but it doesnt order by Percent using ggplot. How it should be @Яaffael?

Comment: Ok, now that you've removed all reference to stringsAsFactors, I think you're getting somewhere. Depending on what they want, `cut` might be useful.

Comment: Sorry Do not Order @Яaffael

Comment: this gets too confusing ... I bail out, Sainora friends and good luck

Comment: Sorry Again @Яaffael, order is fine, but woth ggplot, it doesnt show chart ordered by Percent

Comment: "Jon Skeet helps those who help themselves." as we say here on Stackoverflow